# Content negotiation using mod_rewrite / RewriteCond rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, github-pages, content-negotiation, linked-data

I have a use case is to host [a set of files](https://github.com/nandana/nandana.github.io/tree/master/foaf) (same RDF content with different serialization formats such as RDF/XML, Turtle, and JSON-LD) in Github pages and use [a w3id URL](https://w3id.org/) as a permanent identifier.

Further, I want to have content negotiation on that permanent URL. This would be trivial if I hosted my files in an Apache server but unfortunately Github pages don't support content negotiation. So I am trying to see to which extent I can do that with URL rewriting rules.

So the idea is similar to the following.

```
GET http://w3id.org/foo  -- redirect to --> http://foo.git.io/content.ttl
Accept: text/turtle

GET http://w3id.org/foo  -- redirect to --> http://foo.git.io/content.jsonld
Accept: application/ld+json
```

Currently my rules look like the following.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^.*application/rdf\+xml.* 
RewriteRule ^foaf$ http://nandana.github.io/foaf/card.rdf [R=303,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^.*text/turtle.* 
RewriteRule ^foaf$ http://nandana.github.io/foaf/card.ttl [R=303,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^.*application/ld\+json.* 
RewriteRule ^foaf$ http://nandana.github.io/foaf/card.jsonld [R=303,L]
RewriteRule ^foaf$ http://nandana.github.io/foaf/card.html [R=303,L]
```

Though this works for majority of the cases, it would break for some corner cases. For example, if there is an accept header like the following

```
Accept: application/rdf+xml;q=0.9,text/turtle
```

This will return application/rdf+xml (because the first rule matches) though according to the content negotiation it should return turtle. Does anyone know a way to improve the rules to handle this corner case?

Comment: Similar questions: [Mod-Rewrite content negotiation for mixed Accept header?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/76884/17633) (on [webmasters.se]) and [Redirect depending on preferred language (Accept-Language) with .htaccess](http://serverfault.com/q/655834/131794) (on [sf]).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @unor !! Apparently there is no solution for this, isn't it?

Comment: I didn’t find one, but I still hope it’s possible *somehow* (without server-side scripting).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to make 0-byte dummies of the actual files, e.g. `foo.ttl`, `foo.jsonld` etc and make sure their types are declared with `AddType`, then the [regular content negotiation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) can work for `http://example.com/foo`.

But instead of serving the 0-byte files, have `RewriteRule foo.ttl` etc for each file so that they are redirected out to the 'real' location. Quite verbose, yes, but should then work correctly even for complex `Accept` headers with `q=` and multiple types.